# Find size of each compiled module in Python virtualenv?

Tags: python, django, heroku, virtualenv

I have inherited a bloated Django project that is deployed through Heroku and which includes a lot of large libraries (including numpy, scipy, etc). It appears the previous developer froze his whole virtual environment and I am doing my best to prune dependencies that aren't used.

After the need for installing MatPlotlib arose, Heroku gave me an error that the slug size is too large. That library is over 50MB on its own.

```
remote: -----> Compressing...
remote:  !     Compiled slug size: 321M is too large (max is 300M).
remote:  !     See: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-size
```

For the sake of getting this application updated with new features, I want to grep the size of each dependency in this application so I can make a priority list to investigate which are actually used.

**How can I cycle through the list of dependencies in my requirements.txt file and view the compiled size of each module?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you have a virtual environment set up and all your dependencies are in `site-packages`, you can get close by simply doing:

```
du -sh /path/to/site-packages/* | sort -hr
```

Here's the output on my machine:

```
29M     .../site-packages/django
7.0M    .../site-packages/pip
6.5M    .../site-packages/ckeditor
6.2M    .../site-packages/grappelli
5.2M    .../site-packages/IPython
...
```

Of course, that doesn't distinguish between your dependencies and the dependencies of your dependencies, or take into account `.slugignore`, but it might be good enough.